# creating and publishing python package in offline environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pipenv

The main problem is, to create such a package in offline environment, you need to pack all the dependencies that it requires within the package.

Then when you will install it, it won't need to look at any other repo or path to find them, they will be included in the package.

Anyone has any idea how to accomplish such a thing?
Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+offline

Comment: You don't create a single package with dependencies, you download all dependencies and move them to offline hosts along with your package.